# Spring boot connecting to mariadb hosted in local docker

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb

Below is spring very basic starter application which is trying to connect to mariaDB which is running on docker locally & somehow spring is not able to connect to the mariaDB but when tried to connect from SQL Client with same credentials/configuration its looks fine.

Error:-

[image]

[image]

Application properties:-

[image]

Dependancies:-

```
<dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mariadb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>r2dbc-mariadb</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mariadb</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your pom.xml or check there are correct dependencies:

```
 <groupId>org.mariadb</groupId>
 <artifactId>r2dbc-mariadb</artifactId>
```

```
 <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
 <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
```

Comment: Please check updated pom

Comment: I never use devtools with r2dbc - Is 
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
accessible in classpath ?

Comment: If not - then add it

Comment: BTW - Consider use spring-boot-starter-webflux for full reactive way and async data handling

Comment: Actually this setup is all working fine on windows System, its giving issues with only on Mac

Comment: Still same error? If not please update question or paste here new problem